# Relative Layout v/s Grid Layout for Android

Tags: android

So I'm developing an android application and I need to create a homepage which is similar to the Windows 8 Start screen.

I tried the grid layout and from what I have read, there are limitations with this type of layout.

The tile size for each item should be such that it can be changed as per the content of the blocks.
So for this case is the relative layout better than the grid one? I don't want to put a scrolling functionality. Just intend for the tiles to be able to expand/collapse and automatically configure their sizes.
And is there a function to make the tiles "live" somehow? Maybe show some text or images, etc.

And in terms of flexibility, which one is more versatile?

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is use gridlayout.Because grid layout is very simple to make text and image view similar to windows 8 start screen.For relativelayout you have to put some effort more than grid.And also gridlayout make widget as u want live.More clarification you can refer this page.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/GridLayout.java

Comment: Does the relative layout not support live function? What other methods are there apart from grid and relative? Also, does gridlayout allow flexibility in terms of the widget size. According to the content that the widget or the button is linked to, will the widget size expand accordingly with the help of the wrap_content? How can that be done...

Comment: @user2742298 Live function means what do u mentioned here?.u want more example on grid layout consist of bitmap image and text?.